# Solana - leader validator and incrementing field

Tags: solana

As I understand it, Solana will elect a leader each round and there will be multiple validators handling the transactions independently. The leader will then consolidate all the transactions.

From this understanding, I'm curious how Solana actually handles programs which increment a field. So lets say we have this counter field, which increases by 1 each time the program is called. What happens if 10 different users calls this program at the same time, how will this work if the 10 transactions are handled by the ten validators independently. For example at the start of the round, `counter=50` and during the round, ten different validators handles the transactions separately so each validator will increase the `counter=51`. When the leader gets back all the txns, it will say `counter=51`, what happens in this scenario?

I feel like there is something missing in my assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my understanding here seems to be incorrect. It is actually the leader who executes the transactions and the validators who are verifying the transactions.

Source
Page 2 - Section 3 - https://solana.com/solana-whitepaper.pdf

**As shown in Figure 1, at any given time a system node is designated as
Leader to generate a Proof of History sequence, providing the network global
read consistency and a verifiable passage of time. The Leader sequences user
messages and orders them such that they can be efficiently processed by other
nodes in the system, maximizing throughput. It executes the transactions
on the current state that is stored in RAM and publishes the transactions
and a signature of the final state to the replications nodes called Verifiers.
Verifiers execute the same transactions on their copies of the state, and publish their computed signatures of the state as confirmations. The published
confirmations serve as votes for the consensus algorithm.**

Answer (score 0):

The "recent blockhash" is another important part of this.  A transaction references a recent blockhash, which is part of the Proof of History sequence.  If two transactions reference the same blockhash, they are counted as duplicates by the network, even if they come from two different users.

More information can be found at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#recent-blockhash

Comment: It is important to note that the transactions must be identical to be considered as duplicate. Two different txs referencing the same blockhash are not considered duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one PoH generator(Block producer) at a time. other nodes are just validating.

I cannot comment to Jon C but the answer is wrong. you can use the same recent blockhash otherwise there is no way solana can handle 50000 tps when block time is around 0.4 sec.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).